# Adding an li element with text component on click with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

This is what I've done so far - but I also need to handle and empty comment, clear the field after submission and post multiple comments. Don't want answers really - just hints as to where I need to look and if I'm completely off base.

```
function registerClickHandler() {
   var commentButton = document.getElementByID('postComment');
   commentButton.onclick = addComment();
}

function addComment() {
    var list = document.getElementByID('commentList');
    var commentContent = document.getElementByID('comment')
    var newComment = document.createElement('li');

    newComment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(commentContent));
    list.appendChild(newComment);
}
```

---

```
<ul id='commentList'>
</ul>
<form>
   <input type='text' id='comment'/>
   <input type='button' id='postComment' value='Post'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to this code [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Gng86q8SY6ItyTvlVzIK?p=preview), basically you have syntax error:

> change all ocurrencies of getElementByID for getElementById

```
document.getElementByID('postComment');
```

for

```
document.getElementById('postComment');
```

> And call the function which define the click handler

```
registerClickHandler();
```

> Get the value for the element

```
var commentContent = document.getElementById('comment').value;
```

Comment: Man - getId...it's always something like that. And thank you so much for the other stuff too. At least I was somewhat on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

- There's no `getElementByID` function, only `getElementById`, because javascript is case-sensitive.
- `commentButton.onclick = addComment();` is wrong because you call `addComment` function instead of assigning it as an event-handler to the onclick event. You should remove the parentheses `commentButton.onclick = addComment;`.
- Use `document.getElementById('comment').value;` to get or set the value of your text input.